# Python EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python

i am trying to create a output file for to use in a class project but it keeps giving the an EOL while scanning string literal on this line: `outfile = open(r'C:\Users\kay\Documents\CCA Classes\CIS 119\numbers.txt', 'w')`. I know the "\" is a special character but my book says the r prefix makes it a raw string which should make this the file location.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#This program creates the number file 
import os
def main():
     #Get how many numbers from the user
     many_num = int(input("Enter how many numbers ' + \
                            you will be adding: '))

     #Open a file for writing
     outfile = open(r'C:\Users\kay\Documents\CCA Classes\CIS 119\numbers.txt', 'w'")

     #Get the numbers and write to the file
     for count in range(1,many-num +1):
          numbers = int(input('Enter a number: ' + \
                               str(count) + ': '))

          #write number to file
          outfile.write(str(numbers) + '\n')

     #Close the file
     outfile.close()
     print('Data written to numbers.txt.')

#Call main function
main()
```

Comment: `you will be adding: '` ---> `'you will be adding: '`

Comment: Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare this two lines, second is correct (you can use double or single quotes, it doesnd matter). By using double quotes you are passing two arguments as one string with single quotes and comma inside:

```
#outfile = open(r"C:\Python33\numbers.txt', 'w'")
outfile = open(r'C:\Python33\numbers.txt', 'w')
```

Comment: I put this in and it is still giving me the EOL error and highlighting the ( right after the n of open

Comment: @Maggi3339336 Check quotes, this line - string begin with double quote and end with single: `many_num = int(input("Enter how many numbers ' + \`